# Umbraco Whole Content Autosaving

Tags: umbraco, autosave

I am wondering if it is possible to autosave all the contents in Umbraco so that we don't lose any edits should something happen to the server or browser?
I am aware of the solution of autosaving rich text editor, but at this stage, I want to autosave Whole the contents (rich text editor and the rest)
I am using Umbraco version 7.11.1

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Preserver.Umbraco/

This package stores state in local storage, then prompts to restore it when returning to the page (ie if the browser crashes, power cut, etc). 
So no autosave, due to versioning, but enables restoring the unsaved changes.
This means that if for any reason we lose the server, the local version can be restored later. 
This is a property editor for rescuing content changes developed by Nathan Woulfe.